# Kentico V8 - Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, kentico, azure-application-gateway

We are working to move our Kentico Site to Azure.  Currently we are still running on the Compute model with IIS server back-end.  We are also working on adding Azure Application Gateway as part of the infrastructure.  When we setup the rules for the site and configure the application gateway we continue to get 502 errors.  We have tested and confirmed the site is working expected.  When to try and connect via IP:Port you get license error since we are only licensed for certain URL.  Any suggestions on how to get this working properly?

Comment: _We have tested and confirmed the site is working expected_ -- does that mean `200 OK`? Because if the response is anything but, the App Gateway will mark that leg failed.

Comment: we tested going direct to the site using the proper URL by adding a Host file.  This allowed direct testing.  my Understanding is the App Gateway checks via IP:Port and since that is not licensed it fails with a 503.

Comment: Don't assume, look at the logs. It must send a Host header, otherwise, that's not HTTP/1.1, it's madness.

Comment: We had to create a custom health probe to point to a file on the server so it would bypass the Kentico license for healthcheck.

Comment: Then Kentico is what they call _not cloud ready_, you should suggest them to return a 200 OK even when presenting the licensing conundrum to the user. It may not be a human! BTW, you should have your own .aspx doing custom checks, i saw people pointing probes at LICENSE.TXT on WordPress sites, of course that's always going to light up green even if the database died days ago.